# send image from ImageView as email attachment

Tags: android, email, imageview, attachment

How can I know filename of ImageView image? 
I want to send it as email attachment.

UPDATE:  I don't use images from resources. I have images from android storage(as in contacts app) using:

new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);

and from camera. Camera is OK - I can get filepath. But storage is question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't, as images can be from a variety of sources.  What you can do is get the [bitmap cache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29) with the same result of sending the image.

Comment: I have images from android storage(as in contacts app) using:  Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null) and from camera. Camera is OK - I can get filepath. But storage is question

Comment: If you're talking getting them from the sd card or internal storage, you may have to scan the media for image files.

Answer (score 3):

If the image is a resource that you provide then you can get the path to the image. The format is:

"android.resource://[package]/[res id]"

[package] is your package name

[res id] is value of the resource ID, e.g. R.drawable.example

You can then pass this as an extra in your create e-mail intent like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//Mime type of the attachment (or) u can use sendIntent.setType("*/*")
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
//Subject for the message or Email
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Picture");
//Full Path to the attachment
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.example));
//Use a chooser to decide whether email or mms
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't use images from resources. I have images from android storage(as in contacts app) using: Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null) and from camera. Camera is OK - I can get filepath. But storage is question

Comment: try having a look at content providers, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html i think thats what you need, i did something similar a while back i'll have a look for it and post the code if i can find it.

Comment: Kenny, the attachment filename is a number instead of a filename when using this method. Is there a way to rename that attachment before sending, without having to save to SDcard?